# Transform input for json field

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have data that looks like this:

```
[{"key": "key1", "value": "value1"}, {"key": "key2", "value": "value2"}, ...]
```

I want to save it to `jsonb` field in following format:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", ...}
```

Is it possible to transform initial array to json in `postgres` at `insert` time or my only option is to transform it earlier in app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=827a93470452c8880e4e092f1ea7f159)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_object_agg(elem ->> 'key', elem ->> 'value')
FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements('[{"key": "key1", "value": "value1"}, {"key": "key2", "value": "value2"}]'::jsonb) elem
) s
```

1. Expand array elements into one row each (`jsonb_array_elements`)
2. Aggregate them together (`jsonb_object_agg`) by extracting the `key` value as new key and same with `value`

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the way you do the query to retrieve the data, the framework used,... need more info to answer.

In order to format the json as you want I will use the map() function like this:

```
var initialArray = [{"key": "key1", "value": "value1"}, {"key": "key2", "value": "value2"}, ...];

var newArray = initialArray .map(function (el) {
   var obj=new Object;
   obj[el["key"]]=el["value"];
   return(obj);
});
```